# Let $(a_n)_{n\ge1}$ be a positive sequence with limit $0$ such that $|f(x+a_n)-f(x)|=a_n$, for every positive integer $n$ and real $x$. Find $f$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity

> Let $(a_n)_{n\ge1}$ be a sequence of positive numbers with limit $0$ and $f$ a continuous function such that $|f(x+a_n)-f(x)|=a_n$, for every positive integer $n$ and real $x$. Find $f$.

Now, it is clearly that I have to prove $f(x)=x+c$ or $f(x)=-x+c$, but I am not sure how. For the particular sequence $a_n=1/n$, I tried to use some inequalities, and that led me to $f(x+r)-r\le f(x)$ and $f(x+r)+r\ge f(x)$ for every real $x,r$, but I don't now how to prove that if $f(x)=x+c$ for some $x$, then $f(y)=y+c$ for every real $y$ and something like $f(y)=-y+c$ cannot happen in this case and the other way around in the second case. I know this is a particular case, but if I would have been able to prove it, I think I could use the proof and try to show that $ma_n$ are dense in the real positive numbers. Please, help me. I'm begging you, at least give me some hints for it, even for the particular sequence $a_n=1/n$.

Comment: Use \le instead of <= and \ge instead of =>.

Comment: Yes, the function is continuous. I've mentioned that in the title, but someone edited it.

Comment: And that's why I told that if we prove $f(x+a_n)=f(x)+a_n$ or $f(x+a_n)=f(x)-a_n$ holds for all real $x$ and positive integer $n$, then is way easier. For the sequence $a_n=1/n$, I was able to solve it, but again, the interger denominator played a big role.

Comment: @LucasMcAllister Don't bother about the title, but I really suggest you should edit the QUESTION to add that $f$ is supposed to be continuous. Also, if $f$ is assumed to be continuous my current answer does not apply, so I'm deleting it.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Done.

Comment: Good. Now the question looks much more reasonable to me, and I wouldn't be surprised if I or someone else found a satisfying solution soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're asking only for a hint :
For every $n$ and $x$, there is a sign $\varepsilon_n(x)\in\lbrace \pm 1\rbrace$ such that $f(x+a_n)-f(x)=\varepsilon_n(x)a_n$. Now, $\varepsilon_n$ is a continuous function of $x$ (why?), can you finish from here ?

Comment: Well, yeah, thanks. Actually, I had this all along, but I didn't noticed how useful it actually is. In fact, it's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that $f$ is differentiable (which is not
necessary the case since $f(x+a_n)-f(x)$ can be equal to $(-1)^n a_n$)

Then, for all $x$, you have $|Df(x)|=|\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}|=|\lim_n\frac{f(x+a_n)-f(x)}{a_n}|=1$.

If you assume that $f$ is $C^1$, then $Df=1$ or $Df=-1$ everywhere.

Let $g:x\mapsto x$ and $h :x\mapsto-x$, since $\mathbb{R}$ is open and connected and $D(f-g)=0$ everywhere or $D(f-h)=0$ everywhere, $f=g+C$ or $f=h+C$.

Comment: Okay, but how do you know that $Df(x)$ exists ? I mean, if $\lim_n\frac{f(x+a_n)-f(x)}{a_n}$ exists, it does not mean that $Df(x)$ exists cuz this is just one particular sequence with the limit 0.

Comment: Yes totally, so the problem the way you asked it could in theory have other solutions, i gave you the $C^1$ solutions.

Comment: Okay, I understand now, when I first tried to solve it, I had a similar approach, but using the the existence of the first derivative is just one particular case and the problem looks way more complicated. Anyways, thanks for your help, and if you have any other ideas, let me know.